# How do I use `instanceof` to create a type guard for an array of custom types in typescript?

Tags: arrays, typescript, typeguards

Say I have an array of dogs:

```
const thePound = new Array<Dog>();
for (let i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
  thePound.push(new Dog(randomDogName()));
}
```

How do I differentiate an array of dogs from an array of cats using the `instanceof` operator?

I've tried the a few things but they all give me typescript errors that I don't understand, so I think I'm missing the proper syntax and I can't find any examples of anyone doing this anywhere.

```
// Is it a dog pound or a cat pound?
function (thePound: Dog[] | Cat[]) {
  // Parsing error
  if (thePound instanceof Array<Dog>) {
  // Syntax error
  if (thePound instanceof Dog[]) {
  // Generic types have issues too
  if (thePound instanceof Dog<Pug>[]) {
```

I'm aware there are other ways of doing this which guarantee at runtime that the array is indeed filled with dogs, but I'm not interested in doing that deep introspection -- I'd like to simply write an `instanceof` type guard and call it good, but I'm clearly missing something.

Comment: you can only use the `instanceof` operator on class instances. If it is an array of class instances, it will not work. You would have to check each element in the array individually.

Comment: TypeScript compiles to JavaScript from which the static typescript has been [erased](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/basic-types.html#erased-types).  At runtime there are no generics and thus no `Array<Dog>`, there is only `Array`.  You can check if `thePound` is an instance of `Array` but this won't help you.  Your only option is to do a runtime check; given `Dog[] | Cat[]`, you don't need to check *all* entries, just one, like [this](https://tsplay.dev/mAK9Qw).  If that meets your needs I can write up an answer. If not, what am I missing?

Answer (score 1):

You can use a function returning a type assertion value, but I don't think it works for generics.

```ts
interface Dog {
  foo: string
  bar?: number
}

function isDogArray(array: any[]): array is Dog[] {
  // do needed checks, returning true or false
  return array.every(x => typeof x?.foo === 'string')
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm author of [ts-narrow](https://github.com/axle-dev/ts-narrow) library, and I came up with this solution here:

```js
export const isInstanceOf =
  <Target extends Function>(e: Target) =>
  (target: unknown): target is Target["prototype"] =>
    target instanceof e;
```

You can check file isInstanceOf.ts on the repository, and also other advanced narrow functions